# Alter each element of a list with a for cycle using javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a list of elements and that in each element of the list there are two div elements. I want to move the content of the first div inside the second div. My for cycle fails on the 2nd cycle giving me this error:

> Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

I suspect this is because the script is trying to move the children of the first list element inside the second. How can I solve this oddity?

This is my function:

```
  post = document.querySelectorAll(".post");
  postsall = post.length;
  hidereply = document.querySelector(".post .first a.move_this");
  namereply = document.querySelector(".post .second .third .reference");
  inforeplyall = document.querySelectorAll(".post .second .third");
  for (i=0; i < postsall; i++) {
    inforeplyall[i].insertBefore(hidereply, namereply);
  }
```

I want to take each element and move `move_this` before `reference`.
This is a sample of my HTML page:

```
<div class="post" id="1">
    <div class="first"><a class="move_this"></a></div>
    <div class="second"><div class="third"><span class="reference"></span></div></div>
</div>
<div class="post" id="2">
    <div class="first"><a class="move_this"></a></div>
    <div class="second"><div class="third"><span class="reference"></span></div></div>
</div>
<div class="post" id="3">
    <div class="first"><a class="move_this"></a></div>
    <div class="second"><div class="third"><span class="reference"></span></div></div>
</div>
<div class="post" id="4">
    <div class="first"><a class="move_this"></a></div>
    <div class="second"><div class="third"><span class="reference"></span></div></div>
</div>
<div class="post" id="5">
    <div class="first"><a class="move_this"></a></div>
    <div class="second"><div class="third"><span class="reference"></span></div></div>
</div>
```

[image]

---

I tried editing my function like this but no result

```
  post = document.querySelectorAll(".post");
  postsall = post.length;
  for (i=0; i < postsall; i++) {
    hidereply = post[i].querySelector(".first a.move_this");
    inforeplyall = post[i].querySelectorAll(".second .third");
    namereply = post[i].querySelector(".second .third .reference");
    post[i].insertBefore(hidereply, namereply);
  }
```

Comment: The sample html doesn't match your query structure. Please post a sample of the actual html that you are using.

Comment: I forgot do edit, I'm sorry. I edited, not it should be the same

Answer (score 0):

The second param of `node.insertBefore()` must be the child of the `node`, your `namereply` is just the child of `inforeplyall[0]` because the `document.querySelector` just return the first node, and `querySelectorAll` return all nodes in order, so, you change your code:

```
hidereply = document.querySelectorAll(".post .first a.move_this");
for (i=0; i < postsall; i++) {
    namereply = inforeplyall[i].querySelector('.reference')
    inforeplyall[i].insertBefore(hidereply[i], namereply);
}
```

At last, I edit the code:

```
var post = document.querySelectorAll(".post");
var postsall = post.length;
var hidereply;
var inforeplyall;
var namereply;
var parentEle;
for (i=0; i < postsall; i++) {
  hidereply = post[i].querySelector(".first a.move_this");
  inforeplyall = post[i].querySelectorAll(".second .third");
  namereply = post[i].querySelector(".second .third .reference");
  parentEle = namereply.parentNode;
  parentEle.insertBefore(hidereply, namereply);
}
```

Because when using `pNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode)`, the `pNode` must be the referenceNode's parentNode.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try it straight away! You forgot a semicolon

Comment: I imagine that `hidereply` would similarly need moving inside the loop.

Comment: @skirtle yeah, thanks, I edit the answer, maybe the OP need to move the five hidereply to before the reference respectively.

Comment: inforeplyall[i].insertBefore(hidereply[i], namereply); result in the same error?

Comment: @hiru sorry, I find the other error, that, when using the `pNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode)`, the `pNode` must be the referenceNode's parentNode. I edit my answer, please have a look. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

Comment: "Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'". I tried entering each line in the console and only the last one with insertBefore is causing an error

Comment: Ah! I did it! With less functions than expected! Your link really helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One of the instructions I was missing was the parentNode, necessary for insertBefore that strictly relies on the presence of the parent of its elements to work. [The link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46249406/alter-each-element-of-a-list-with-a-for-cycle-using-javascript#comment79465336_46249478) JiangangXiongposted posted was really helpful, if you have troubles with insertBefore or appendChild, you should first try with a sample HTML template on JSFiddle helping yourself with a Wiki.

New HTML Template for testing:

```
<div class="thread">
    <div class="post">
        <div id="1"><a class="move_this">Hello</a></div>
        <div class="post reply">
            <div class="postInfo"><span class="name">...</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div id="2"><a class="move_this">Hello</a></div>
        <div class="post reply">
            <div class="postInfo"><span class="name">...</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div id="3"><a class="move_this">Hello</a></div>
        <div class="post reply">
            <div class="postInfo"><span class="name">...</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div id="4"><a class="move_this">Hello</a></div>
        <div class="post reply">
            <div class="postInfo"><span class="name">...</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <div id="5"><a class="move_this">Hello</a></div>
        <div class="post reply">
            <div class="postInfo"><span class="name">...</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working function:

```
var post, moveThis, moveTarget, targetParent;
post = document.getElementsByClassName("post");
for (i=0; i<post.length; i++) {
    moveThis = post[i].querySelector(".post div .move_this");
    moveTarget = post[i].querySelector(".post .post.reply .name");
    targetParent = moveTarget.parentNode;
    targetParent.insertBefore(moveThis, moveTarget);
}
```